# How to defer loop wrapped $http get request in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, promise, http-get, deferred

I have a function that checks for for records and if they exist it downloads them for each item.  This is a function that happens with in a loop so there can me many records.   I thought that I was using $Q properly to deffer each $http request to wait for one after each other so they do not all happen at the same time but they all fire at the same time still.

I have seen $q.defer(); but do not understand how to use it in my implementation.  How would this be written properly deferring each call until the one before is complete?

```
CheckRecords: function(obj) {
    var promise;
    var promises = [];

    if (obj.BD.img == 'checkedRecord') {
        var objBDUrl = 'services/GetSurveyBD/?id=' + obj.BD.ID;
        promise = $timeout(function(){
                $http.get(objBDUrl, { cache: true }).then(function(response) {
                    obj.BD.ID = obj.BD.ID;
                    obj.BD.data = response.data;
                });
            }, 250);
        promises.push(promise);
    }
    if (obj.MR.img == 'checkedRecord') {

        var objMRUrl = 'services/GetMR/?id=' + obj.MR.ID;
        promise = $timeout(function(){
            $http.get(objMRUrl, { cache: true }).then(function(response) {
                obj.MR.ID = obj.MR.ID;
                obj.MR.data = response.data;
            });
        }, 250);
        promises.push(promise);
    }
    $q.all(promises).then(function(){
        return obj;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `$q.all` just ensures that all requests completed, the requests are still executed immediately, but their results are deferred. If you want to control the execution order you, do your requests in the result function.

Answer (score 0):

$q
- service in module ng
A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing.